# Mouse button event on a disabled checkbox in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a tricky problem, I need to do some action when a user is making a right-click on a checkbox, but this checkbox can be disabled (`IsEnabled="False"`) for business logic reason.
The problem is that even the `previewMousDown` event is not raised when the `CheckBox` is disabled.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to make your problem more specific and with the code you will ask then it will be more easier

Answer (score 4):

You could have a MouseDown eventhandler on a control higher up in the VisualTree and use HitTest to figuer out if your checkbox would be "RightClicked"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx

Answer (score 3):

surround your CheckBox with a ContentControl and handle that event on the ContentControl